# Google picker method "setSelectableMimeTypes is not a function" error in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-picker

I am trying to use google picker API in Google app script, to allow the user to select the folder to which the document to be uploaded. I am using the following code

**HTML FILE**

```
function change_destination()
{
 gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function(){pickerApiLoaded = true;}}); 
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker).getOAuthToken();
}
function createPicker(token) 
{
   var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView().setSelectFolderEnabled(true).setParent('root');
   var callback = function(data) 
   {
    if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED)
    {
     var doc = data.docs[0];
     console.log("You picked " + doc.id);
    }
   };
   var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().setSize("650","470").setOAuthToken(token).addView(docsView).setOrigin('https://docs.google.com').setCallback(callback).build();
   picker.setSelectableMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
   picker.setVisible(true);
}


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

**CODE.gs**

```
function getOAuthToken() 
{
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

Am getting the following error "setSelectableMimeTypes is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `setSelectableMimeTypes` before the picker is build.

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
       .setSize("650","470")
       .setSelectableMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder') //not sure about this Mime type
       .setOAuthToken(token)
       .addView(docsView)
       .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
       .setCallback(callback)
       .build()
   picker.setVisible(true);
```

To display only folders in the picker view.

```
 var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS).setParent('root');
   var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
       .setSize("650","470")
       .setOAuthToken(token)
       .addView(docsView)
       .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
       .setCallback(callback)
       .build()
   picker.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Drive picker won't allow to create folder...the work around is to create the folder before the picker is used, using `DriveApp.createFolder("<<Input from user>>").getId()`. Then you can pass on the id to the picker

Comment: I get the following error " Uncaught TypeError: this.Jf is not a function", when i try to use the code 'To display only folders in the picker view'. Also am interested in knowing is there any method to create a folder and then select the same using these APIs @Ritz

Comment: I am able to display the folders....maybe a configuration issue...[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529641/allow-multiple-files-upload-on-google-apps-script/45531077#45531077) for more details regarding the configuration

Comment: I too got the folders displayed when i used the code, but got the above mentioned error, when i tried to select the folder .when i used `DocsView().setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')` instead of  `DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS)` it worked. @Ritz