# Allow Multiple Files Upload on Google Apps Script -Not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created an HTML web app form to allow submitter to submit the data with attachment (multiple files) attachment and maths function is not working. However, I am able to record the form data in the sheet.

I want to allow submitter to submit data from form and attachment links should be updated in sheet.

Please help me to identify fix the issue.

Script is attached below,
[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fA5qPNfoegZoEpl1al3XudNEyvomgAbko5XDBA_i7aw/edit#gid=0)

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setTitle("Testing");
}


function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

}


function getCurrentUserEmail()
{
  var email={'email':Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()};//returned as an object
  return email;
}


function saveDate(data) {
    var openSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fA5qPNfoegZoEpl1al3XudNEyvomgAbko5XDBA_i7aw").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var sheetHeader = openSpreadSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, openSpreadSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    Logger.log(sheetHeader);
    var arrayToSave = [];
    data["Timestamp"] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "IST", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    data["Email Address"] = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
    for (i = 0; i < sheetHeader.length; i++) {
        if (Object.keys(data).indexOf(sheetHeader[i]) != -1) {
            arrayToSave[i] = data[sheetHeader[i]];
        } else {
            arrayToSave[i] = "";
        }
    }       
    openSpreadSheet.appendRow(arrayToSave);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>123</title>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Icons-->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

 <style>
  /*.form-group.num, .form-group.txt {
   margin-bottom:0; width:100px; display:block; clear:both; margin:0 auto}
   .form-group.txt { width:inherit;}*/
   th {    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e3f2fd;color:#263238 !important}
 tr.one th{   
    background-color: #f5f5f5;color:#263238 !important}
 
  
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
.navbar-default { background-color:#0a3474}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #0a3474;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
 color:#fff}
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
   color: #0a3474;
    background-color: #FFF;
  }
.gap10{
 height:10px; display:block; clear:both;}

th {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009e16;
    color: #fff !important;}

  
  </style>


<style>

  #attachmentTable{ 
  background: white;
  }
  tr th,tr td{
  text-align: center;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="" alt="Dispute Bills">
        </a>
        
      </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> : <h9 id="email"></h9></a></li>
     
    </ul>
        </div>

  </nav>
  
  </div>
  
</div>


<hr>
<form name="newpurchase" action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:65%;margin:0 auto">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th  colspan="4">Procurement Request Form</th>
      
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Request Type </td>
        <td>
        <div class="form-group">
        <select name="supplier_name" class="form-control select" id="RequestType">
        <option value="Supply">Supply</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
        <option value="Software">Software</option>
        
       </select></div></td>
        <td>Urgency</td>
        <td> <div class="form-group"><select name="supplier_name" class="form-control select"id="Urgency" >
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
        
       </select></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Requester For</td>
        <td> <div class="form-group"><select name="supplier_name" class="form-control select" id="RequestFor" >
        <option value="Cost for Approval">Cost for Approval</option>
        <option value="PO Process">PO Process</option>
        
       </select></div></td>
        <td>Currency</td>
        <td> <div class="form-group"><select name="payment_mode" id="select"  class="form-control select" >
        <option value="INR">INR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
       </select></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Requester Name </td>
        <td>
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="contact_person" class="form-control input-md"  id="RequesterName"/></div></td>
        <td>Business User</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="contact_person" class="form-control input-md"  id="BusinessUser"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Short Description:</td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control input-md" id="ShortDescription" name="address_line2"></textarea></td>
        <td>Business Reason:</td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control input-md" id="BusinessReasonforRequestPurpose" name="address_line2"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container">
  <td><table id="productList" class="table table-bordered">
    
      <tr>
        <th  colspan="9">Requested Material/Service Details-Cost</th>
      
      </tr>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr id="head"> 
        <td>SR No</td>
        <td>Product/Material/ServiceDescription</td>
        <td>Make & Model No</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total Price </td>
        <td>GST% </td>
        <td>Total Price with GST </td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
       <td  align="center">1</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription1"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo1"></div></td>
      <td> <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM1" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice1"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY1"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"   class="subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price1"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST1" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" class="total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice1"name="total"/></div></td>
                       
      </tr>
       <tr> 
 <td  align="center">2</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription2"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo2"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM2" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice2"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY2"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"   class="subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price2"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST2" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" class="total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice2"name="total"/></div></td>
                       
      </tr>
       <tr> 
        <td  align="center">3</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription3"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo3"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM3" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice3"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY3"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"   class="subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price3"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST3" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" class="total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice3"name="total"/></div></td>
                        
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td  align="center">4</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription4"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo4"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM4" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice4"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY4"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"   class="subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price4"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST4" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" class="total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice4"name="total"/></div></td>
                       
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
       <td  align="center">5</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription5"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo5"></div></td>
      <td width="120"><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM5" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice5"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY5"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"   class="subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price5"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md"  class="gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST5" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" class="total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice5"name="total"/></div></td>
                        
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></td>
</div>


<body style='font-family: cursive;'>
  <div>
    <left><button onclick='getOAuthToken()' style="margin-top:50px;outline:0;" class="btn btn-success">Upload File(s)</button></left>
  <div class='table-responsive' style="display:none;" id="attachmentTableDiv">
  <table id="attachmentTable" class="table table-bordered" style="width:900px;margin:20px auto;float:none;">
      <thead>
        <tr style="background:#f1f1f1;">
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>URL</th>
          <th>Date Created</th>
          <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
    
 <hr>
 
 
  <div class="container">
          <div  class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
            <button style="width: 100%;" type="submit" id="updateBtn" class="btn-btn-success" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>
          </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="input-field col s12" id = "progress">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div id="success" style="display:none">
        <p>Your Data  has been successfully uploaded.</p>
      </div>
<hr>



<script>
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'AIzaSyD9UvBsf_wdqxpTFgxzWhRtaI-VfITb_RY'; 
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }


    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker).getOAuthToken();
    }


    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
      // var all         = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS); //To upload from Google Drive
       var uploadview  = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent('0B0Oj_1v-CAzNYmFMRkVUZjd0aHM');  //To upload from local machine..Add you google drive folder
       var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(uploadview)
            //.addView(all)
            .hideTitleBar()
            //.setLocale('nl') //--Regional language settings
            //.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setSize(536, 350)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the response object. 
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        for(var i in data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS]){
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][i];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        var dateCreated = doc[google.picker.Document.LAST_EDITED_UTC];
        var date = new Date(dateCreated);
        date=date.toLocaleString();
        $('#attachmentTable tbody').append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+id+"</td><td><a href='"+url+"' target='_blank'>Link</a></td><td>"+date+"</td><td><a href='https://drive.google.com/drive/uc?export=download&id="+id+"'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></i></a></td></tr>");
        $('#attachmentTableDiv').show();
      }
    }
}
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>google.load("picker", "1", {callback:function(){pickerApiLoaded =!0}});</script>


    <script>

      var file, 
          reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        if (e.target.error != null) {
          showError("File " + file.name + " could not be read.");
          return;
        } else {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
            .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result, file.name, $('input#name').val(), $('input#email').val());
        }
      };

      function showSuccess(e) {
        if (e === "OK") { 
          $('#forminner').hide();
          $('#success').show();
        } else {
          showError(e);
        }
      }

      function submitForm() {

        var files = $('#files')[0].files;

        if (files.length === 0) {
          showError("Please select a file to upload");
          return;
        }

        file = files[0];

        if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
          showError("File Size is more than 5 MB");
          return;
        }

        showMessage("Uploading file..");

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      }

      function showError(e) {
        $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      function showMessage(e) {
        $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
      }


    </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
          $(function () {
            $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot');
            var $tblrows = $("#productList tbody tr");

            $tblrows.each(function (index) {
                var $tblrow = $(this);

                $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', function () {

                    var qty = $tblrow.find("[name=qty]").val();
                    var price = $tblrow.find("[name=price]").val();
                    var subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

                    if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                        $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                        var grandTotal = 0;

                        $(".subtot").each(function () {
                            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                        });

                        $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            });
        });



var $price      = $("input[name='subtot']"),
    $percentage = $("input[name='gst']").on("input", calculatePrice),
    $total   = $("input[name='total']").on("input", calculatePerc);
    

function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = $(this).val();
    var price = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.subtot').val());
    var calcPrice  = (price + ( price * percentage / 100 )).toFixed(2);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.total').val(calcPrice);
}

function calculatePerc() {
    var total = $(this).val();
    var price    = $price.val();
    var calcPerc = 100 - (total * 100 / price);
    $percentage.val( calcPerc );
}

    </script>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dispEmail)
      .getCurrentUserEmail();
     });//runs after dom is loaded
     function dispEmail(data)
     {
       $('#email').text(data.email);//put's email into h1 tag
     }
     console.log('My Code');    
     

        function submitForm(btnClicked) {
            $("button").attr("disabled", true);
            var jsonObj = {};
            jsonObj["Requester Name"] = $("#RequesterName").val();
            jsonObj["Business User"] = $("#BusinessUser").val();
            jsonObj["Request Type"] = $("#RequestType").val();
            jsonObj["Request For"] = $("#RequestFor").val();
            jsonObj["Short Description"] = $("#ShortDescription").val();
            jsonObj["Business Reason for Request/Purpose"] = $("#BusinessReasonforRequestPurpose").val();
            jsonObj["Urgency "] = $("#Urgency").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(1)"] = $("#SNo1").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(2)"] = $("#SNo2").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(3)"] = $("#SNo3").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(4)"] = $("#SNo4").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(5)"] = $("#SNo5").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(1)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription1").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(2)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription2").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(3)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription3").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(4)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription4").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(5)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription5").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(1)"] = $("#MakeModelNo1").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(2)"] = $("#MakeModelNo2").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(3)"] = $("#MakeModelNo3").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(4)"] = $("#MakeModelNo4").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(5)"] = $("#MakeModelNo5").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(1)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(2)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(3)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(4)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(5)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(1)"] = $("#QTY1").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(2)"] = $("#QTY2").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(3)"] = $("#QTY3").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(4)"] = $("#QTY4").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(5)"] = $("#QTY5").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(1)"] = $("#UnitPrice1").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(2)"] = $("#UnitPrice2").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(3)"] = $("#UnitPrice3").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(4)"] = $("#UnitPrice4").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(5)"] = $("#UnitPrice5").val();
            jsonObj["Price(1)"] = $("#Price1").val();
            jsonObj["Price(2)"] = $("#Price2").val();
            jsonObj["Price(3)"] = $("#Price3").val();
            jsonObj["Price(4)"] = $("#Price4").val();
            jsonObj["Price(5)"] = $("#Price5").val();
            jsonObj["GST(1)"] = $("#GST1").val();
            jsonObj["GST(2)"] = $("#GST2").val();
            jsonObj["GST(3)"] = $("#GST3").val();
            jsonObj["GST(4)"] = $("#GST4").val();
            jsonObj["GST(5)"] = $("#GST5").val();
            jsonObj["Total Price(1)"] = $("#TotalPrice1").val();
            jsonObj["Total Price(2)"] = $("#TotalPrice2").val();

            jsonObj["Upload the documents )"] = $("#files").val();
            jsonObj["updateBtn"] = $(btnClicked).text();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSaving).saveDate(jsonObj);
            return false;
        }

        function afterSaving() {
            alert("Thanks, Your response has been recorded");
            $("button").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    </script>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529641/allow-multiple-files-upload-on-google-apps-script)

Comment: Could you please provide the logs? And in want line are you encountering the error?

Comment: @abielita
Please find the Logs below
[17-09-18 10:45:31:909 IST] Starting execution
[17-09-18 10:45:32:301 IST] DriveApp.getRootFolder() [0.379 seconds]
[17-09-18 10:45:32:302 IST] ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() [0 seconds]
[17-09-18 10:45:32:303 IST] Logger.log([ya29.GlzKBCVy1nDep5JMNCNB3MfBDcB1i2ffGIYwndp_qdxCOWdgav6ritsIBBDnCE9aSWA5vzBGOC1dFWFilWzCYtNLbUZyBvd6vVIlkdwfJYGVz8HSmPizssi_BhBGag, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-09-18 10:45:32:303 IST] ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() [0 seconds]
[17-09-18 10:45:32:305 IST] Execution succeeded [0.383 seconds total runtime]
Not getting any error messgae in code